# How to use FontForge to merge two font files with different font-size, same letter-spacing and bottom aligned

Tags: fontforge

For 'different font-size', I change the Em-size of font-info. So that in the same font-size, one font will bigger than the another. When I use this merged font in photoshop, and set font-size to 56px in one text element. It will show like this.
[image: Demo]

But the letter-spacing between '123' and 'ABC' isn't same. And also they are not bottom aligned. What I want this merged font is like this.
[image]

So how change this text alignment, let '123' and 'ABC' in the bottom aligned. And how to change letter-spacing to make '123' to be more tight.